# How can I put a different TextView (with a different content) on the two LinearLayout inside the FrameLayout provided by default of a TabHost?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tabhost

How can I put a different TextView (with a different content) on the two LinearLayout inside the FrameLayout provided by default of a TabHost wherein the textview1 for example with a text of "Category A" will shown if the first tab widget is being selected or clicked, while the textview2 for example with a text of "Category B" will shown if the second tab widget is being selected?
Anyway, I'm currently using a fragment to display the whole layout where the tabhost is located, here is my layout with the tabhost.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/thesis" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mon_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/collegetitle" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="HEADLINE NEWS!"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/c" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mon_head_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Today is the launch of the newest PLP E-Magazine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mon_head_sender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mon_head_desc"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:text="Written by: Shaira Casandra Libao"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mon_head_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mon_head_title"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mon_head_title"
            android:text="PLP E-Magazine is the answer for those aspiring PLPians who are willing to write articles for everyone!"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pBcollegebul"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mon_head_title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                 <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                  </TabWidget>

                   <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tab1"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tab2"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So to use the above widgets, and as an alternative to the onCreate() method of Activity Class, I'm using onCreateView() for Fragment Class. I know that I have something to fix in the java code to add a tabwidget and give names to it, and to display the specified textview if a specific tabwidget is selected or clicked.

(Forgive me for using tabhost which is currently deprecated, It's just because I'm using eclipse as my IDE)